# Precision field in printf when formatting integer

Tags: c, printf

When I execute these two lines:

```
printf("%.5d\n", 3);  // use of precision filed
printf("%05d\n", 3);  // use of 0 flag to prepend with 0
```

I get the following output:

```
00003
00003
```

The same result

So I wonder what is the meaning of the precision field for integer types

Comment: Please [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ecbz014.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `%d`, the precision is the minimum number of digits to print.

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> The precision
>
> An optional precision, in the form of a period ('.')  followed by
>   an optional decimal digit string.  Instead of a  decimal  digit 
>   string  one  may    write "*" or "*m$" (for some decimal integer m) to
>   specify that the precision is given in the next argument, or in the
>   m-th argument, respectively,    which must be of type int.  If the
>   precision is given as just '.', or the precision is negative, the
>   precision is taken to be zero.  **This gives the    minimum  number  of
>   digits to appear for d, i, o, u, x, and X conversions**, the number of
>   digits to appear after the radix character for a, A, e, E,    f, and F
>   conversions, the maximum number of significant digits for g and G
>   conversions, or the maximum number of characters to be  printed  from 
>   a    string for s and S conversions.

For positive values, this works out to be the same as giving the same value for the field width and a `0`  flag.  If the value is negative, the negative sign will take up one character in the width of `%05d`.

```
printf("%.5d\n", -3);  // use of precision filed
printf("%05d\n", -3);  // use of 0 flag to prepend with 0
```

Output:

```
-00003
-0003
```