# C Programming: Does Modulus Ignore Leading Zeros in Result ? How Can I Stop It?

Tags: c, modulo, modulus

I'm programming a microcontroller in C and since the compiler or chip doesn't handle Floating Point numbers very well, it is recommended to scale the floating point value up enough to get rid of the decimal and then when outputting the number, scale it back down with a proportional division and use modulus to find and display the fractional part. Here's an example:
Start with number `25.0625`. Multiply by `10000` to get `250625`. Good now we don't have a float anymore. Now to display this we use a line like this:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%li.%i", Temp / 10000, abs(Temp % 10000));
```

So we first get the `25` back out by `/ 10000`, then we get the `0625` out by `% 10000`. Here's the problem though: It appears my modulus result ignores the leading zero in 0625 so when it concatenates the number back together, it becomes `25.625` instead of `25.0625`. I can't count on there always being a leading zero, so stuffing a zero in there isn't the answer, and there could at other times be several leading zeros. My question is, how do I suppress the modulus from excluding leading zeros ? Thanks.

Comment: Leading zeros don’t exist numerically; use `%04i` to format an integer as four digits wide.

Comment: Numbers don't have leading zeroes, they're just numbers. You can use `%04d` format to print it with 4 digits.

Comment: BTW, `sprintf(buffer, "%li.%i", Temp / 10000, abs(Temp % 10000));` is certainly wrong output with `Temp  = -123`.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell `sprintf` to format the number in a 4-digit field with leading zeroes.

```
sprintf(buffer, "%li.%04d", Temp / 10000, abs(Temp % 10000));
```

See [Printing leading 0's in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153890/printing-leading-0s-in-c)

Comment: Also `%.4d` does the same job.  There are some who argue it is preferred over `%04d`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't see that recommendation in any of the answers to the question I just linked to.

Comment: It does seem to be missing.  I’d want to dig up a reference for “there are those who…” before going much further.  The x-red is also about zip codes rather than integer/fixed-point arithmetic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394291/precision-field-in-printf-when-formatting-integer) is a question that discusses the difference, which only affects negative numbers. In my experience, `%04d` is more idiomatic.

Comment: I went digging.  The [C99 Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) documents this (p152): _The use of leading zero in field widths to specify zero padding is superseded by a precision field.
The older mechanism was retained._  The commentary applied to the C90 standard too (it wasn't added for C99).  I'd not dispute that you see `%04d` at least as often as `%.4d` in many circles.  It was intended to be an informative comment rather than serious criticism.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I also find the `0` modifier to be more mnemonic, and it's consistent with formatting floating point (for which the precision specifies digits after the decimal).

Comment: Note that this outputs `"0.1234"` for `Temp = -1234;` where certainly `"-0.1234"` is desired.

Comment: @chux Good point, because integers don't have negative zero for `-1234/10000`. The code needs to check for this case.